# How to switch between two fragments in android TabLayout?

Tags: android

how to switch between `Fragment A` and `Fragment B` in android `TabLayout`.

how to switch to next Fragment when Fargment Button `Onclick` is called.

Please help me

[image]

[image]

```
package com.digi.global.globalhub.fragment.offer;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.digi.global.globalhub.R;
import com.digi.global.globalhub.Utility.M;
import com.digi.global.globalhub.listener.FilterListener;
import com.digi.global.globalhub.listener.FragmentMove;
import com.digi.global.globalhub.listener.OfferFilter;


public class OfferFragmentActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    PagerAdapter adapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    Context context;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ImageView bizMenu;
    PopupMenu popup;
    public static OfferFragmentActivity mInstance = null;

    public OfferFragmentActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static OfferFragmentActivity newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        OfferFragmentActivity fragment = new OfferFragmentActivity();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        context = this.getContext();
        mInstance = this;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offer, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getContext());
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        bizMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bizMenu);
        bizMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bizMenu.setOnClickListener(this);


        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.biz_ic, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault));
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_menu_white_36dp);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#B68426"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.Offers));


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(final TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        if(fragment instanceof OfferFilter){
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.bizTravel:
                    ((OfferFilter) fragment).onFilterBizTravel("bizTravel");

                    return true;
                case R.id.bizAssistance:
                    ((OfferFilter) fragment).onFilterAssistance("bizAssistance");
                    return true;
                case R.id.bizSolution:
                    ((OfferFilter) fragment).onFilterSolution("bizSolution");
                    return true;
                case R.id.partners:
                    ((OfferFilter) fragment).onFilterPartner("partners");
                    return true;
                case R.id.favoutites:
                    ((OfferFilter) fragment).onFilterFavouritesBiz("favoutites");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        String tabTitles[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.offerTab);
        Context context;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabTitles.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

           /* FragmentMove fragmentChanges = (FragmentMove) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 2);
            if(fragmentChanges instanceof FragmentMove) {
                ((FragmentMove) fragmentChanges).fragmentChanges();
            }*/
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentOne();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentTWO();
                case 2:
                    return new FragmentThree();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabTitles[position];
        }

       /* public View getTabView(int position) {
            View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_text_layout, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tabText);
            tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
            return tab;
        }*/

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a FragmentPagerAdapter to manager fragments and set this adapter into viewPager to slide fragments when you click on tabs or swipe to change tabs.

FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private final String[] mTabsTitle = {"Fragment A", "Fragment B, "Fragment C"};
private Context context;
private int[] mTabsIcons = {
        R.drawable.a,
        R.drawable.b,
        R.drawable.c};

public TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

public View getTabView(int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(mTabsTitle[position]);
    title.setSingleLine(true);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(mTabsIcons[position]);
    return view;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {

        case 0:
            return new FragmentA();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentB();
        case 2:
            return new FragmentC();

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mTabsTitle[position];
}}
```

How you use it:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
```

You need a TabLayout:

```
mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    if (mTabLayout != null) {
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        //populate your tabs
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            if (tab != null)
                tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }

        TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(0);
        if (tab != null && tab.getCustomView() != null) {
            tab.getCustomView().setSelected(true);
        }
    }
```

How to select a page:

```
private void selectPage(int pageIndex) {
    mTabLayout.setScrollPosition(pageIndex, 0f, true);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageIndex);
}
```

Do not forget to create your customTab.xml.

Best regards.

Comment: selectPage where to use

Comment: selectPage, in my case, I used when I click on sideMenu(Navigation View).

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment A's onClick() method, try this :

```
   TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();
    tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(2);
```